How to write unit test for PHP Script without functions?
I'm trying to write a unit test for a PHP script that does not contain any functions or classes.
It is just a plain PHP script that returns header('Location: ${url}') when a specific condition is met.
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include XOOPS_ROOT_PATH . "/include/curl/functions.php";
include "ADBConnection.php";
include "MDBConnection.php";

global $user;
if (!empty($user) && is_object($user)) {

    $a_connection = new ADBConnection();
    $m_conn = new MDBConnection();
    $conn = $a_connection->getConnection();
    $a_connection->setSqlQuery($some_sql);

   $prepare = $conn->prepare($db_connection->getSqlQuery());
   $prepare->execute([
       "user_id" => $user->customer_id(),
   ]);
   $result = $prepare->fetchAll();

   $is_allow = false;
   if (!empty($result)) {
      foreach ($result as $item) {
          if ($item['is_allow'] > 0) {
              $is_allow = true;
              break;
          }
      }
   }

  $user_admin = $m_conn->getUserAdmin($user->uid());
  if ($is_allow || $user_admin === true) {
      header("Location: ${some_url}");
  } else {
    header("Location: ${another_some_url}");
  }
} else {
  header("Location: /");
}

Below is what I've tried to write a test case for that script file.
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->userMock = $this->getMockBuilder(User::class)
        ->setMethods(['customer_id', 'uid'])
        ->getMock();

    $this->axDatabaseMock = $this->getMockBuilder(ADBConnection::class)
        ->setMethods()
        ->getMock();

    $this->marcDatabaseMock = $this->getMockBuilder(MDBConnection::class)
        ->setMethods(['getUserAdmin'])
        ->getMock();
}

public function test_redirect_user_to_some_url_page()
{

    $this->userMock->method('customer_id')
        ->willReturn(1);
    $this->userMock->method('uid')
        ->willReturn(1);

    $this->marcDatabaseMock->method('getUserAdmin')
        ->willReturn(true);

    ob_start();
    require('path_to_script');
    $headers = xdebug_get_headers();
    $this->assertContains('Location: ${some_url}', $headers);
}

When I tried to debug the returned value of $headers it gave me this:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(38) "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
}

It seems like it does not return an expected result.
So how can we write unit test for a PHP file script?
I also checked with other answers but didn't figure it out.

You could enable error reporting, or check the error logs, there might be an error in the file you include in the test.

"that does not contain any functions or classes" - why not refactor your code to make it more testable?

You should write a function like isUserAllowed() and test that function.

Using error_reporting(0) while debugging can lead to hidden  problems

first: "Hello world" -> second: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objektorientierte_Programmierung -> third: writing tests
